# How to resolve ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.connection.BufferProvider?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to write simple java code which shows the MongoDB collections on console. I have added mongodb-driver-3.0.0.jar in my classpath.

But when I try to execute the code, it is giving me following error at the line of Database connection:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/mongodb/connection/BufferProvider     at
>   com.chintan.app.MongoDbJdbc.main(MongoDbJdbc.java:12) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.mongodb.connection.BufferProvider     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 1 more

Following is my code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017); //Exception

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mydb");
        System.out.println("Database connection successfull.");
        ...
        ...
    }
```

What is the problem here? Do I need to add another jar in classpath or there is some version problem?

Comment: can you show your imports?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

On the mongo driver page here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/installation-guide/#mongodb-driver

You'll see the following text:

*Note: mongodb-driver requires the following dependencies: bson and mongodb-driver-core*

So you need all of the following jars to make this work:

*mongodb-driver-3.0.1.jar, mongodb-driver-core-3.0.1.jar, bson-3.0.1.jar*

Which can be downloaded from here:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.0.1/
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/3.0.1/
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/bson/3.0.1/

Comment: For later readers: Pay attention to take the newest version of the jars. Just navigate to the parent directories and pick the newest ones...

Comment: Also, for later readers, this is the correct answer, I just don't know why it wasn't marked as the right one.

Comment: This saved me some time. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The following java driver contains the BufferProvider class:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This class is in the `mongodb-driver-core-3.0.0` jar file which is required by `mongodb-driver-3.0.0.jar`. You can see java drivers dependencies in the [POM file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.0.0/mongodb-driver-3.0.0.pom) associated with this jar.
I think you have to use a dependency manager to automatically add MongoDB (and other components) transitive dependencies to your project (maven, gradle, ...).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have maven project, just include mongo-java-driver-3.6.1.jar (this jar is only for Java) in your project no need to include other jars.

Answer (score 0):

include mongo-java-driver-3.11.0.jar file in class path not in Module path.