# NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClientURI

Tags: java

```
    package com.sm.mongo;

    import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
    import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
    import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
    import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
    import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

    public class JavaMongoConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //System.setProperty("jdk.tls.trustNameService", "true");

        MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
                "mongodb+srv://admin:admin123@cluster0-bkruu.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
            MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");

    }
}
```

This is my code, and whenever I run this code, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClientURI
```

I looked at [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using MongoDB driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122018/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-when-using-mongodb-driver) and I tried their solution where I went to Run Configurations --> Dependencies and looked under Classpath Entries to make sure that I have bson-xxx.jar, mongodb-driver-xxx.jar, and mongodb-driver-core-xxx.jar listed. I have these listed and despite this, I keep getting the same error as in that stackoverflow post.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need `mongo-java-driver` dependency

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com/mongodb/MongoClientURI` class is present in `mongo-java-driver` jar. https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/

Including the above jar in classpath should fix the issue